# Monitoring tools to check and alert for connection issues from on-prem to databases or services in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, alarm, cloudwatch-alarms

Are there any monitoring alerting tools that can monitor and create alarms for any connection problems from the connecting source and the AWS databases as destinations?
For example, is there any tools that can monitor instances from an on-prem instance (Source) where they connect to AWS RDS or RedShift. Currently on-prem are connected to an AWS environment using vpn and I want alerts of the instances experience connection issues to the database.
I don't see any of these for cloudwatch on the destination side as they monitor mostly resource allocation, number of connections which isn't helpful because we have a variable amount of connections.

Thanks